# How to select current date on wijmo datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, wijmo

How do we select current date on wijmo date picker.

Currently, am not able to select selected date again.

Is there any property or event call back do i need to set?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code to add value to wijmo date picker

```
let inputDate = new WjInput.InputDate(editorRoot);
                            inputDate.format = 'add your date picker format'
                            inputDate.value = 'add your value here'
```